# MASM beats unoptimised .cpp but not unoptimised .c using VS

Tags: c++, c, performance, visual-studio-2012, optimization

I have a very simple function that transforms a vector (float*) using a row major matrix (float**):

```
int vector_by_matrix(float** m, float* v, float* out, int size)
{
    int i, j;
    float temp;

    if (!m || !v || !out) return -1;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        temp = 0;

        for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
                temp += m[i][j] * v[j];
        }


        //out[i] = temp * v[i]; MISTAKE DURING COPYING - SHOULD'VE BEEN...
        out[i] = temp;``
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code was originally being compiled as C++ (x64) using the Visual Studio (2013) C++ compiler; and without optimisation was quite slow (the function was being called hundreds/thousands of times during a run and the size of the system is typically large c. size = 10000). With optimisation being set high (**O2**) and floating point mode set to **fast** the performance gain was huge (x20). However, I decided to convert the file to a .c source file and compile as C using VS again - it was simple procedural code anyways. The performance improved again (over the optimised C++ compilation) with or without optimisation. In fact, the optimisation settings had little affect on the performance.

I don't understand why the C code is always faster (optimised/unoptimised). I disassembled the output from the C(/C++) compiler and it looks horrendous - I originally wrote the same function in MASM and it was about a fifth of the code but couldn't compete in terms of speed. Does the VS always optimise compiled C code? It certainly looks like it from the disassembled code but I can't be sure. My MASM code if it helps:

```
 mul_vector_by_martix proc

    mov r10, r9

    sub rsp, 8

    mov qword ptr[rsp], r11

    LI:
        MOV rbx, qword ptr[r10*8+rcx[0]-8]

        XORPS xmm0, xmm0

        mov r11, r9

        LJ:

            MOVSS xmm1, dword ptr[r11*4+rbx[0]-4]
            MULSS xmm1, dword ptr[r11*4+rdx[0]-4]
            ADDSS xmm0, xmm1

            sub r11, 1

        jnz LJ

        MOVSS dword ptr[r10*4+r8[0]-4], xmm0

        sub r10, 1
    jnz LI

    mov r11, qword ptr[rsp]

    add rsp, 8

    ret

mul_vector_by_martix endp
```

I won't supply the disassembled code - the question is long enough ;)

Thanks in advance for any help.

### Update

I got round to look into this again today. I have implemented the packed instructions (current implementation only works where the system size is a multiple of 4 else you'll likely get a crash):

```
mul_opt_vector_by_martix proc

    sub rsp, 8
    mov qword ptr[rsp], r12
    sub rsp, 8
    mov qword ptr[rsp], r13 

    ; copy rdx for arithmetic operations
    mov r10, rdx

    ; init static global
    mov r12, LSTEP

    cmp VSIZE, r9
    je LOOPS

    ; get sizeof(vector)
    mov rax, 4
    mul r9
    mov r12, rax

    ; get the number of steps in inner loop
    mov r11, 16
    mov rax, r12
    div r11

    mov r11, rax

    mov r12, r11

    mov rax, 16
    mul r12
    mov r12, rax
    sub r12, 16

    mov VSIZE, r9
    mov LSTEP, r12

LOOPS:

    LI:

        MOV rbx, qword ptr[r9*8+rcx[0]-8]

        XORPS xmm0, xmm0

        mov r13, r12

        LJ:

            MOVAPS xmm1, xmmword ptr[r13+rbx[0]]
            MULPS xmm1, xmmword ptr[r13+r10[0]]

            ; add the packed single floating point numbers together
            MOVHLPS xmm2, xmm1
            ADDPS xmm2, xmm1
            MOVAPS xmm1, xmm2
            SHUFPS xmm2, xmm2, 1 ; imm8 = 00 00 00 01
            ADDSS xmm2, xmm1
            ADDSS xmm0, xmm2

            sub r13, 16

        cmp r13, 0
        JGE LJ

        MOVSS dword ptr[r9*4+r8[0]-4], xmm0

        sub r9, 1
    jnz LI

    mov r13, qword ptr[rsp]
    add rsp, 8
    mov r12, qword ptr[rsp]
    add rsp, 8

    ret

mul_opt_vector_by_martix endp
```

It improves things by about 20-30% but again can't compete with the unoptimised compiled C code. The disassembled code for the inner loop:

```
                sum += v[j] * m[i][j];
 movsxd      rax,r8d  
 add         rdx,8  
 movups      xmm0,xmmword ptr [rbx+rax*4]  
 movups      xmm1,xmmword ptr [r10+rax*4]  
 lea         eax,[r8+4]  
 movsxd      rcx,eax  
 add         r8d,8  
 mulps       xmm1,xmm0  
 movups      xmm0,xmmword ptr [rbx+rcx*4]  
 addps       xmm2,xmm1  
 movups      xmm1,xmmword ptr [r10+rcx*4]  
 mulps       xmm1,xmm0  
 addps       xmm3,xmm1  
 cmp         r8d,r9d  
 jl          vector_by_matrix+90h (07FEDD321440h)  
 addps       xmm2,xmm3  
 movaps      xmm1,xmm2  
 movhlps     xmm1,xmm2 
addps       xmm1,xmm2
movaps      xmm0,xmm1  
 shufps      xmm0,xmm1,0F5h  
 addss       xmm1,xmm0
```

At this point I have to concede I can't see where the gains are. I haven't bothered rebuilding the code as C++ to see if the assembly is different but I suspect that in unoptimised mode the C++ just doesn't lend itself to fast code as C does with the VS compiler. Perhaps Frankie_C's point is pertinent. What worries though is that if the compiler is doing something it shouldn't - I can't see much wrong though; in my experience any half decent hand written assembly will outperform unoptimised C but not here with this compiler. Floating point operations need strict control on issues of precision otherwise results can vary from one machine to another and methods that need to converge can even fail on one machine but not another due to instabilities.

Update 2=====================================================================

It seems like this has went very quiet but I thought I'd let you all know if I got any more improvement. Well I can match the compiler by rearranging some of the operations in the loops as shown in the last update. It was quite obvious just moving the - packed - shuffling and addition to outside the inner loop. Again due to the implicit size of "vectorisation", the size of the system has to be a multiple of 4 (crash otherwise).

```
LOOPS:

    LI:

        MOV rbx, qword ptr[r9*8+rcx[0]-8]

        XORPS xmm0, xmm0

        mov r13, r12

        LJ:

            MOVAPS xmm1, xmmword ptr[r13+rbx[0]]
            MULPS xmm1, xmmword ptr[r13+r10[0]]

            ; just add and accrue
            ADDPS xmm0, xmm1

            sub r13, 16

        cmp r13, 0
        jge LJ

        ;------------ moved this block to the outside --------------;

        ; add the packed single floating point numbers together
        MOVHLPS xmm1, xmm0
        ADDPS xmm1, xmm0
        MOVAPS xmm0, xmm1
        SHUFPS xmm1, xmm1, 1 ; imm8 = 00 00 00 01
        ADDSS xmm0, xmm1

        ;--------------------end block---------------------------

        MOVSS dword ptr[r9*4+r8[0]-4], xmm0

        sub r9, 1
    jnz LI
```

Still can't beat the compiler but getting very close to equalling it. I suppose the conclusion is it is very hard to beat the VS compiler when it comes to even unoptimised C - this is not my experience with (unoptimised code) other compilers such as gcc. **I can out-perform the compiler by unrolling the loops using the SIMD instructions wiht more xmm regsiters.** I can supply this on request but it is probably self-explanatory.

Comment: What you mean with "C compiler disassemble is horrendous"? Compiler techniques privilege instructions execution times, and, hard to believe, some constructions using more instructions works faster. C++ suffer of the huge and complex language framework, that limits the optimizations and put in the executable a lot of unuseful code. C is linear and bare code.

Comment: @Frankie_C: well, I have to disagree with the second part. C being "linear" depends on the compiler. That said: a compiler (when properly instructed) uses *all* possible tricks, from memory alignment to reordering individual instructions. Even if the base algorithm is sound, that's hard to beat by a human writing assembly.

Comment: Thanks Frankie_C. I am aware that latency overhead can become significant with some instructions never mind make code prone to cache misses etc. But I still don't understand why the unoptimised code and optimised code is always faster. The disassembled code was not even using the stack pointer. BTW I wouldn't expect to be able to outperform a modern compiler's optimisation with my own asm; but unoptimised code?

Comment: Jonhware I agree with all that and I'm not arguing that I should be able to complete with the optimised compiler. But I should be able to beat the unoptimised compiler and if the compiler is doing something that I haven't told it to - it shouldn't it could have huge implications for numerical stability between machines. The unoptimised C++ code is slower than my MASM code. So I can't see why the same isn't true of the unoptimised compiled C.

Comment: Post the disassembly anyway, it's the only way to be sure. (an excerpt is probably fine, if it's ridiculously long)

Comment: Sorry just noted a mistake in the title - now fixed.

Comment: As I said C is very simple and has no framework, so the op's translation is already optimized. The following optimizations (i.e. peephole, etc) don't have a large work to do. You have to see it in the reverse way: is not C more optimized, but it is C++ that is more complex due to the framwork. Then in optimization the compiler, if you don't use C++ specific features,  can remove a lot of dead code and almost resemble C.

Comment: @Frankie_C I disagree completely, none of that is an issue here. There's no "framework" stuff in sight. The only things that matter here are things like vectorization, using multiple accumulators, scheduling, etc.

Comment: @Jongware C is linear meaning that it is composed of a prologue to setup stack, the user code that can be translated to assembler 1:1 by definition, and an epilogue to clean stack and return. C++ have to deal with polymorfism, inheritages, overloading, virtual calls...

Comment: Frankie_C I should have mentioned this is a .dll project. The function is darn-well as good as part of the API and the bottleneck is in this function (so this is pretty lightweight). I have done similar things with gcc and never had this issue. The hand-crafted assembly always beats the unoptimised C build. This is why I am surprised. This is the first compiler I have encountered this issue with.

Comment: harolld I'll get that code for you. Tomorrow if that is ok as it is very later here and I should be in bed ;) Thanks guys this is a great forum.

Comment: Tell us exactly what you measured and how you measured it. Benchmarking is tricky to get right.

Comment: Large code - could it be loop unrolling? Or some extra code for cache optimization?

Comment: Doh! harold and others I had one more look at the disassembled code and it is using single float packed "operands" rather than low single precision operands. This will reduce he number of inner loops by factor of 4 - I've used this before with little effect but I'll have a look again tomorrow - probably the reason.

Comment: If you're actually interested in speed too in addition to "weirdness", see if [this](http://pastebin.com/TjptsVL0) is any better (it does make some additional assumption about the size, but you can just pad with zeroes to make it true) (also, using even more accumulators may be better, particularly on Haswell). If you look at the assembly generated, you should then be able to beat the compiler on the original code.

Comment: harold thanks. As I say I'm working principally in C but I did implement your C++ code and yes it runs very fast in unoptimised mode too. It is a bit slower than the C but by very little (again using VS). The only thing is it is not getting what looks like the right answer - but I think it is fair to assume it is doing the same amount of work - "all the right note just not in the right order" :). I need to run this through g++ if I get the chance. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: harold I noted a mistake in the C code - it must have happened during copying and editing (see sample above).

Comment: @cdcdcd ok well, that code makes more sense now. But this is getting more suspicious by the day. If even [this](http://pastebin.com/eK0wBnpD) (if compiled with optimization) is beaten by the unoptimized code, that's conclusive evidence that the unoptimized benchmark is cheating.

Comment: harold no there has been a mixup here. The unoptimised code is beating the assembly I wrote - this is not my experience with other compilers such as gcc. Optimisation makes very little difference (nominally) to the run times for the C or the C++ you supplied (again this is not what I've experienced with other compilers). In short, I think the VS compiler does a lot of work by default - the disassembled code suggests everything is vectorised in both compilation modes. I can do a few things to speed things up such as the __restrict directive in the C code but it is only by nominal amounts.

Comment: @cdcdcd how did you compile then? /Od (default level) normally generates shit code.

Comment: Yip /Od, and yet it was better than my hand written assembly. But then O2 and /Ox made little difference.

Comment: harold I actually took a bit more time to analyse my assembly and decided I could unroll the outer loop (label L1) by exploiting more of the SIMD registers. Not very elegant but did allow me to beat compiler in either optimised/unoptimised mode. After reassessing the disassembled code it looks like the compiler is doing something similar as default - but boy does it go around the houses to do it?!

Answer (score 4):

Benchmarking is a little bit more tricky than that.

For example, using clang, the following code compiles down to **exactly** the same code in main, ***regardless of whether the call to `vector_by_matrix` is commented out***.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    auto constexpr N = 512;
    float* m[N];
    generate_n(m, N, []{return new float[N];});

    float v[N], out[N];

    float start = 0.0;
    for(auto& col : m) iota(col, col+N, start += 0.1);
    iota(begin(v), end(v), -1.0f);

    //vector_by_matrix(m, v, out, N);

    for_each(begin(m), end(m), [](float*p) { delete[] p; });
}
```

The compiler recognizes that no observable behaviour is changed, so it can leave the thing out.

Of course, as long as you actually inspect the assembly, things should be fine. (Although, had the `vector_by_matrix` function be marked a file-static, it would not even appear in the listing :)).

However, if you're doing any measurements, make sure you use statistically sound analysis and are measuring what you think you are measuring.

See assembly:

- gcc 5.3: https://goo.gl/wIvWsE
- gcc 5.3 with the call commented: https://goo.gl/Z9hLsZ
- clang 3.7: https://goo.gl/xidrS6
- clang 3.7 with the call commented: https://goo.gl/gUc4Ux

### Full Listing For Reference

```
int vector_by_matrix(float** m, float *const v, float *out, int size) {
    int i, j;
    float temp;

    if (!m || !v || !out)
        return -1;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        temp = 0;

        for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            temp += m[i][j] * v[j];
        }

        out[i] = temp * v[i];
    }

    return 0;
}

#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    auto constexpr N = 512;
    float* m[N];
    generate_n(m, N, []{return new float[N];});

    float v[N], out[N];

    float start = 0.0;
    for(auto& col : m) iota(col, col+N, start += 0.1);
    iota(begin(v), end(v), -1.0f);

    vector_by_matrix(m, v, out, N); // NO DIFFERENCE IF COMMENTED

    for_each(begin(m), end(m), [](float*p) { delete[] p; });
}
```

Comment: Thanks sehe. I have ran this through a profiler and the bottleneck is in these functions.

Comment: You'll be more convincing if you show that code. Perhaps with profiler results

Comment: The code that you used when you ran the profiler from which you were able to draw these conclusions. It's the part that's missing. I'd happy to help (validating/improving the benchmark code) but I would need that information

Comment: The initial benchmarking was done crudely using a the stopwatch class in the .NET diagnostics namespace. The time between calling and returing from the dll functions is recoded microseconds: The profiler is ran on the executable it has a fine granularity but only reports on a function basis but highlights in red parts of the code that are most expensive (no metric though that I can see, only for the function). The highlighted portion for the my MASM code is the ADDSS calls but these occur in the disassembled binary more often. Avg times I got for single run (s): C (2.1) vs MASM (3.8).

Comment: I asked >what< you profiled (so we can reproduce it). Anyhoops, it looks like you can't show the stuff, and that's ok. That just means we can't say much about the benchmark validity. I hope this answer, at least, gave you the warning that benchmarking correctly is tricky. I'd use https://github.com/rmartinho/nonius

Comment: sehe essentially the functions as presented were being timed (from cal to return). The disassembled code for the inner loop has also been presented in the update. I'll write a simple console application that calls into the dll. I appreciate all your efforts and would appreciate your views. Hopefully I'll get round to this. I take all your points and agree. However, for me the change in performance is so stark that it is hard to dismiss it and attribute it to my naive appreciation of benchmarking (which compared to yourself is probably fair). Thanks again..

Comment: Humour me if you will and replace your floats with doubles, and measure the effect.

Comment: @Bathsheba who are you talking to? (I just compared disassembly listings to make a point why it's important to show the benchmark code in full. Nothing has come of it. Changing types in my examples is hardly relevant because it will still make the same point)

Comment: Bathsheba that's an interesting request. It is not easy for me to do this as I'd need to change things up though the call stack - else had have costly casting somewhere and then that becomes another issue. I could write a small executable at some stage but I'm still trying to improve performance right now. However, I'd suspect that it may limit what/how the compiler uses the SIMD instructions. If it can it may use the new extended set that work on YMM registers so that performance would not be affected. But if it can't then things would slow down. An interesting request though - worth a look.

Comment: This is why you decouple code. So you can test and benchmark in isolation. Ironically, if you had this done, you'd have had no trouble showing me the code some 8 days ago (and then I, or anyone else, would have gone forward and tweaked it to use doubles among other things)

Comment: @sehe you have the code. Just copy it, create a main function and have a play - the function is very lightweight. Else we could end up going back and forth for weeks - but this is where the bottleneck is!. Looking at the disassembled code confirms it (as supplied). In the end I beat the compiler by unrolling the loops (as stated in the updates). I don't like having to do this as it makes for verbose assembly code (and adds to maintenance overhead when you have to come back to it after a lot of time has passed). But I need to get the job done. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @cdcdcd _"Just copy it, create a main function and have a play"_ - erm. Did you **ever** look at my answer? I /did/ that. And all I can show you is that it's very easy to construct a nonsensical benchmark. If you want to let me consider yours - you need to show it!

Comment: @sehe thanks but I have done about as much benchmarking on this as I need to. I have got it running about 20-30% faster than the compiled code with full optimisation. Job done! Time to move on but thanks for the help.